# Complement of A or B

Tags: probability, statistics

I have a small general question..

Let's say we have two events $A$ and $B$. Is the probability that $A$ *or* $B$ will happen, the complement of the event that the complement of $A$ *and* the complement of $B$ will happen?

I'm sorry if that's hard to understand, I hope it makes sense..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, this is correct. This follows directly from [De Morgan's Laws](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws).

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know about that laws..but I drew a venn diagram and I figured out that it kinda makes sense, but it's good to know that there's actually a law about it.

Comment: It is often convenient to use the venn diagram to remind yourself of De Morgan's laws if you have not memorized them.

Comment: @DanxMindfreak De Morgan's law basically says $(A \cup B)' = A' \cap B'$ and $(A \cap B)' = B' \cup A'$.